# Show related classes like a property in Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I've created 3 new Stereotyps (objStereotyp, color, has color), now I want to create
Objects (class1, class2) of the type "objStereotyp" and Objects of the type "color" (red, green,yellow) and connect each Object("objStereotyp") with one or more color Objects using the new defined "has color" relationship.

Now the Question is how can I list the name of the color stereotyp, which is connected with the "has color" relationship. In the example I added the name as a note, this is what I want to achieve automatic.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "list the name"?

Comment: I mean the colorname. Now I added the image, I hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain the answer is no, you can't do that automatically.

In UML, an attribute and a directed association (with a target role) are semantically equivalent, so what you're suggesting would result in two representations of the same concept.

You could always write a script or an Add-In to do this, but on the whole I wouldn't recommend it. Using both ways to describe the same thing makes it difficult to maintain the model and it is, ultimately, redundant information.

Comment: It wouldn't be redundant, because  the Information is only stored once. The point is that i normally don't want to show the <<color>> Stereotyps in the Diagram, but I want to show that Information anyway.